# Magento 2 - Customer Custom File Attribute unable to save

Tags: customer-attribute, magento2.3, file-upload

I have Created my own Customer Attribute, it was a File attribute. 
While try to upload a file in that, it shows error like,

"`<File Field Name>`" is not a valid file.

While checking in Media folder,

There was sub-folders created under customer folder.

But there was no files there.

Example:

If I upload a file like this, `abcd.pdf` , then it creates folder like this,

```
/pub/media/customer/a/b/
```

Can any one help me to fix the issue.?

Here is my Attribute Creation code

```
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

     $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

      $attributeList['my_file'] = [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'My File',
            'input' => 'file',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 150,
            'position' => 150,
            'system' => 0,
            'validate_rules' => serialize(['max_file_size' => 1048576, 'file_extensions' => 'pdf'])
        ]; 
   foreach ($attributeList as $key => $value) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $key, $value);

        //add attribute to attribute set
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $key)
                        ->addData([
                            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                            'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register', 'adminhtml_customer']
                        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
```

Comment: Show your create attribute code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Magento 2 bug. Its already fixed on Magento2.3 develop branch.
You need to modify below file:

> vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Attribute/Data/File.php

You need to replace below code:

```
if (!empty($value['tmp_name']) && !is_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'])) {
    return [__('"%1" is not a valid file.', $label)];
}
```

By

```
if (empty($value['tmp_name'])) {
    return [__('"%1" is not a valid file.', $label)];
}
```

**Issue [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/19988)**

**Github Reference [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/File.php)**

Comment: I am getting same issue on Magento 2.3.0 Enterprise Edition. Is this still on this version?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost same like Sukumar mentioned. Although, a bit of change worked for me.

```
//edit
    if (empty($value['tmp_name']) && !is_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'])) {
        return [__('"%1" is not a valid file.', $label)];
    }
```